# Can phpunit start with a certain test and then keep going?

Tags: phpunit

I use stopOnFailure in phpunit.  Just my preference.  I'm wondering if there is a way to isolate 1 test and run it, like --filter but then keep going.  So that if my test suite finds a failure half way thru all the tests ... I just want to pick up where I left off when I'm done isolating and fixing.

(Not looking for solutions like paratest)

Comment: I also often use stop on failure, but I also use it not. For that my local test script comes with a --fast switch which fails as fast as possible for any check (in phpunit that is stopOnFailure etc.) but otherwise runs the whole suite Maybe such kind of a procedure works for you as well. Also this is for an older Phpunit version which does not have the --order-by=defects option yet. If you use Phpstorm you can also run the whole suite and re-run only failed tests. Can make sense as well when first collecting all failed ones.

Comment: @hakre - I use storm.  Can you boost my game with a little info about re-running only failed tests?

Comment: Are you looking for info like: [Rerun Failed PHPUnit Tests in PhpStorm 11 (Feb 2016 by Gary Hockin for Intellij)](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2016/02/rerun-failed-phpunit-tests-in-phpstorm-11/) resp. [Rerunning Tests (Phpstorm Help)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/rerunning-tests.html)?

Comment: Thanks!  I've never used the "test runner".  Only command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. But you can configure PHPUnit to start the execution with tests that failed the last time: `--order-by=defects`.

Comment: Holly crap.  It's you.